# Auto-generate multiple PHP files from Template and excel files

Tags: php, html, excel, auto-generate

Auto-generate multiple PHP files from Template and excel files

Am looking for suggestions to efficiently auto-generate multiple PHP (and HTML) files from a template doc pulling fields from an excel file

What I want to do is:
1. Populate the fields in the template file from an excel file, each excel row will generate a new file
2. Save it as a PHP file
3. Name each generated file based on specified field in the correspondig row

I am intentionally trying to multiple and separate static HTML and PHP pages.  Have been using mail merge with word and excel, but, takes to long to resave word file as php and rename, etc.  Not sure how to programmaticaly do this, and my skillset is limited.

Open to different approaches to handle this, appreciate any help and thoughts.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at any libraries such as PHPExcel for reading Excel files from PHP?

Comment: Try looking into how to read and write text files from VBA: you should be able to read in your template file, use `Replace()` to substitute placeholders for your Excel values, then write the updated content to a new file.